# Changing the location of a label and text box

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface

Right now the label is on top of the text box.  I would like to be able to set the location of the text box and label so that the label is to the left of the text box.

```
        this.container = this.getContentPane(); 
        this.container.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 

        this.searchText = new JLabel("Enter text to be searched: "); 

        this.charText = new JLabel("Enter a character: "); 

        this.target = new JTextArea(3,30);
```

Comment: You will find this much easier if you work with a GUI forms editor. WindowBuilder Pro supports Swing, can be plugged into Eclipse, and is now free, thanks to Google. http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wbpro/index.html

Comment: You may want to have a look at group layout:  http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/GroupLayout.html http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/group.html

Comment: I believe your problem has to do with the size of the components. If there's not enough room to fit both the `JLabel` and `JTextArea` in the same row, the Layout Manager will add the latter to a new row. Thus, you'll have the label on top of the text area. In order to get around this, try increasing the dimensions of the `container` and in particular, the `width`. Also, I'm not entirely sure why you have 2 labels, but only 1 text area - care to explain, or provide more code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a JPanel with the FlowLayout.

```
JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();

myPanel.add(searchText);
myPanel.add(target);

container.add(myPanel,FlowLayout.LEFT);
```

Note you should create two panels if you want two labels and two text areas to be displayed in the fashion that you want. For more information on FlowLayout:

[Flow Layout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html)

In any case you should use an editor for more advance positioning.

Comment: He's already using `FlowLayout`, although the align part of your answer may prove useful.

Comment: I definitely disagree with needing an editor for advanced position.  There is not magic provided by an editor.  If you can do it with an editor, then you can do it better by hand.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `GridLayout` like this :

```
    this.container = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2) );     

    this.searchText = new JLabel("Enter text to be searched: "); 

    this.charText = new JLabel("Enter a character: "); 

    this.target = new JTextArea(3,30); 

    container.add(searchText);
    container.add(target);
```